# Arduino Uno, 4x4 Keypad to relay

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

```cpp
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte numRows = 4;
const byte numCols = 4;

int relePin = 10;

char keymap[numRows][numCols] =
{
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

byte rowPins[numRows] = {9, 8, 7, 6};
byte colPins[numCols] = {5, 4, 3, 2};

Keypad myKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keymap), rowPins, colPins, numRows, numCols);


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(relePin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  char keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();
  if (keypressed != NO_KEY);
  {
    Serial.print(keypressed);
  }
}
{
  char key = keypad.getKey();
  if (int(key) == 1) {
    digitalWrite(relePin, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(relePin, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

keypad_til_rele:37: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token

{

^

exit status 1
expected unqualified-id before '{' token

Where is the error ? :/
I do not see where it is???
I'm new to ardiuno

Comment: { char key = keypad.getKey();  What's the '{' token there?

Comment: I suggest showing the full code. Problem may be elsewhere. Anyway, compiler points you to line 37. Also indent the code to make it readable.

Comment: Any tips ? I really need this help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had two extra curly brackets `}` and `{` that closed your main loop prematurely. You have also not declared `keypad` anywhere. I have commented them out below:

```cpp
#include <Keypad.h>

const byte numRows = 4;
const byte numCols = 4;

int relePin = 10;

char keymap[numRows][numCols] =
{
  {'1', '2', '3', 'A'},
  {'4', '5', '6', 'B'},
  {'7', '8', '9', 'C'},
  {'*', '0', '#', 'D'}
};

byte rowPins[numRows] = {9, 8, 7, 6};
byte colPins[numCols] = {5, 4, 3, 2};

Keypad myKeypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keymap), rowPins, colPins, numRows, numCols);


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(relePin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  char keypressed = myKeypad.getKey();
  if (keypressed != NO_KEY);
  {
    Serial.print(keypressed);
  }
  //} These two line are your problem
  //{
  //char key = keypad.getKey(); // keypad was not declared anywhere, I assume it was meant to be this:
  char key = myKeypad.getKey();
  if (int(key) == 1) {
    digitalWrite(relePin, LOW);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(relePin, HIGH);
    delay(1000);
  }
}
```

Comment: keypad_til_rele:37: error: 'keypad' was not declared in this scope

   char key = keypad.getKey();

              ^

keypad_til_rele:44: error: expected '}' at end of input

 }

 ^'

now i got this error :/

Comment: Because you haven't declared `keypad`, I assume it should be `myKeypad` instead. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Sure. No problem, you should also vote up answers that help you :P

Comment: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Hehe, I tried. But got this message :p